# How to display XML RSS feed by PHP

Tags: php, xml, rss

I have an assignment to display my XML RSS via PHP on a website, so far I have tried multiple things and all have failed. And I was unable to find the answer since most people do RSS feed by PHP from MySQL database to get a live feed of posts.

XML RSS

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<rss version="2.0">

<channel>
  <title>Treehouse front page</title>
  <link>https://teamtreehouse.com/</link>
  <description>Programming Tutorials</description>
  <item>
    <title>Code Academy</title>
  <link>https://teamtreehouse.com/</link>
  <description>Programming Tutorials</description>
  </item>
</channel>

</rss>
```

How can I display this file via PHP?

Comment: If I ever mentioned term "gentleman" it was never ment to exclude a part of community. My sincerest apologies if it made that impression.

Wish you have an amazing day!

Comment: No worries Newbie - people making this mistake rarely wish for people to be excluded deliberately. However, I think it's great if everyone can bear these things in mind, so we can get more people feeling like they have a place here `:-)`. Have a good day too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you very much for leading me onto the right track!

But that code would work for DOM file while mine was simplexml.
I used the following code to solve the problem

```
    <?php
$rss = simplexml_load_file('rss.xml');

echo '<h4>'. $rss->channel->title . '</h4>';

foreach ($rss->channel->item as $item) {
   echo '<h4><a href="'. $item->link .'">' . $item->title . "</a></h4>";
   echo "<p>" . $item->title . "</p>";
   echo "<p>" . $item->description . "</p>";
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try to use the [`DOMDocument()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) class, for example:

```
$rss = new DOMDocument();
$rss->load("http://yoursite.com/rss/");

$feed = array();
foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
    $item = array ( 
        'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'desc' => $node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'date' => $node->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        );
    array_push($feed, $item);
}
```

This is a tip. I hope I have helped you.